# No puedo conectar neatbeans a mysql

Tags: mysql, netbeans, mysqlconnector.jar

Tengo neatbeans 12.1 y me voy a servicios conectar le pongo conector j y al intentar conectar con la BD me da este error.

> Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/proyecto?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL using com.

El driver J si esta metido por si cabía alguna duda
Sin embargo si uso neatbeans 8.2 conecta perfectamente. El problema es que quiero usar un plugin para mapeo de bd en JPA y necesito la versión 12 no me vale la 8. os dejo una imagen
[image: Error que se produce]

[image: El drive]

Comment: NO es que no te creamos pero... dónde está _metido_ el jar del driver?

Comment: Ya te he subido una foto tengo 2 el 8 y le 5 y ninguno rula, con la version 8.2  de neatbeans si funciona perfectamente